# Access id of nested object after creation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-attributes

I 'm creating an object through nested attributes in rails and I need to access this object after the creation on the same method.

```
@contact.update(contact_params)
```

This line sometimes creates a child (an address). Is there any way to get the address id if there is one?

Comment: You can always find it. Is it difficult or I am missing something?

Comment: The thing is that the form sometimes creates a child, and sometimes not. How can I get the id of the recently created child if there is one?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm getting you right and you have `one to many` relationship, then you  can do something like this:

```
old_ad_ids = @contact.adresses.ids
@contact.update(contact_params)
new_ids = @contact.adresses.ids - old_ad_ids
```

`new_ids` will be an empty array, if there are no new addresses

Comment, if I missed something.